# How do I flash RasPlex to an SD card from Ubuntu?

Tags: sd-card, disk-image, plex

I'm trying to install RasPlex for my Raspberry Pi 3. When I downloaded the file to flash, it came in a .bin file and the instructions are very weak. So I now have a .bin file and not a clue on how to flash it to my SD card. How do I flash this bin file to the SD card?

Comment: Try to give it execution permissions and execute it. `sudo +x <yourbinfile.bin>; sudo ./<yourbinfile.bin>`.

Comment: What is "the instructions are very weak"? Perhaps they won't look "week" to someone else, so why not elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Download an img image file from official github:
https://github.com/RasPlex/RasPlex/releases

Then flash your SD card:

```
unzip image_name.img.gz
blkid # find out what device you want to flash to, /dev/sdX
dd if=image_name.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1MB #BE VERY CAREFUL you select the right value for X
```

For more information, see the official documentation, [Manual Installation Instructions](http://www.rasplex.com/get-started/download-rasplex.html)

Comment: cheers mate i dont know how you found that link because I went to the link provided and the github page and could only get the .bin file for some reason. but shes working a treat now cheers